# Bootstrap Nested Column alignment issues

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

new to Bootstrap and having some issues with nested columns. for som reason they are disproportionate. First pair of nested columns are "compressed" in half but those in the second are proportioned just fine. see below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-6
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lightcyan;">.col-sm-3</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lightgray;">.col-sm-3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-6</div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lightcyan;">.col-sm-3</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lightgray;">.col-sm-3</div>
      </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Any help on how to fix the alignment would be really appreciates. if this is just a limitation then i guess a new layout will be in order...

thanks,
Marc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of mistakes in your code. First is that your text is showing `col-xs-6` for the nested columns on the left but you are actually setting them `col-xs-6` that's why they were covering half of the width only.

Second one is that you are closing the right div `col-xs-4` before including nested div.

Here's is your working code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-8
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lightcyan;">.col-sm-6</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lightgray;">.col-sm-6</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lightcyan;">.col-sm-6</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lightgray;">.col-sm-6</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```